# "Merge by Distance" is destroying information about double-sided polygons

Tags: mesh, optimization

I have a mesh in which I want all of the faces to display as double-sided (after exporting to a game engine), so I duplicated the mesh with Ctrl+D and flipped the normals. Then I figured I'd optimize the mesh by getting rid of duplicate vertices, so I went into Mesh -> Clean Up -> Merge by Distance. The problem is, this destroys the double-sided faces that I just created.

I'd rather not duplicate the vertex information, but still have triangles be double sided. In computer graphics terminology, triangles with different winding orders, for example, vertices A, B, C would have triangles `[A, B, C]` and `[C, B, A]`. Is this possible to do in Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most game engines just have an option either on the object or its material to enable double sided shading. You don't need to double your mesh load just for that.